# @media print not working properly in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, laravel

I have a problem with CSS in my app. Works fine in Chrome but in Mozzila not. In CSS file I have this code:

mycss.css

```
@media print {
    #printPageButton {
      display: none;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 40px;
      margin-left: -4.8em;
      -webkit-print-text-size-adjust: 10px;
    }    
    div .rTableCell,.rTableHead, .rTableRow{
      border: 1px solid;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    div .rTable{
      margin-top: 55px;
      width: 150%;
      margin-left: -16.6em;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .potpis {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

this code in print mode works fine in Chrome but in Mozilla everything is to big... 
Can you please help me with this stuff.

Comment: the property you are using is not supported by firefox. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) for details

Comment: "Mozzila" … the *company* is called Mozilla (one z, two ls). The *browser* is called Firefox.